# MSI: When shared and invalid states can occur at the same time

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, mesi

So, as the title says, **is it possible that Processor 0 has line A with a Shared (S) state, and Processor 1 has line B with an Invalid (I) state?**

---

Imagine the following situation:

- P0: Line A | Modified
- P1: Line A | Invalid
- P2: Line A | Invalid

If P2 makes a read request for Line A, what is P1 final state? Shared or keeps Invalid?

Comment: It stays Invalid. On Wikipedia there's a state machine for the possible transition. Invalid -> Shared only if the relative processor tries to read the line.

Comment: P2's request for line A does not force a change in the state of P1's cache, but it also does not prevent it.  I.e., no aspect of the correctness of the protocol is violated if line A is updated in P1's cache.  An implementations may use history-based mechanisms to predict when an alternate state transition could lead to better performance -- such as "predicting" that Line A is likely to be read by all cores after being updated and upgrading P2's BusRead to a global broadcast.  (Speculatively converting P2's BusRead to a BusReadX can also be a useful optimization.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

P1's line A will still be in Invalid state. An Invalid state cannot be changed by other processors' actions.
Both P0 and P2 will have line A in Shared state.

---

On the [Wikipedia's page for the MSI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSI_protocol#State_Machine) there's the state machine description of the algorithm.
Along with the English description, there are two pictures.

Given a set of processors and their relative cache lines, a processor can either be "active" by making one action among "load/read" and "store/write", or can be "passive" by snooping an event on the bus.

The input to the MSI (and similar) protocol is either an action or a bus event. For simplicity Wikipedia split the state machine in two: one when the input is an action and one when the input is a bus event.
This way you can use one picture to calculate the new states for the lines of the active processor (which is exactly one) and the other picture for the states of the lines of the passive processors.

Let's say processor X is the active one, thus making a load or a store.

The first picture describes how the cache lines state changes for processor X (the active processor):

[image]

Each label has the form *x/y* where *x* is the input action (either *PrRd* for a load/read or *PrWr* for a store/write) and *y* is the bus event that is emitted ("-" means no event is emitted on the bus).

The second picture is used similarly but for the passive processors (any processor but processor X):

[image]

Each label here is again a *x/y* pair but *x* is a bus event and *y* is a bus action.

The bus events are:

- *BusRd* -> Another processor needs to read a line from memory (or upper cache).
- *BusRdX* -> Another processor needs to read a line from memory (or upper cache) but then will immediately modify it (i.e. because it was doing a *write*).
- *BugUpgr* -> Another processor just wrote to one of its cache line that was only read so far.

Of course, a *Flush* is the act of writing a line to memory. Wikipedia considers it a bus transaction (I consider it a bus action since it's not used as an input).

We are now ready to answer your question.

---

P2 is the active processor and needs to read line A, so it performs a *PrRd*. The first picture tells us that its line A will end up in S state and that a *BusRd* is issued on the bus (note that this is a mental model, real hardware won't probably send a special transaction, rather it will detect the read itself).

```
P2: LineA -> Shared
```

Both P0 and P1 are passive processors and both see the *BusRd*.
P0 has the line in state Modified, the second picture tells us that it will flush the line (making the last value available to P2) and set line A to state Shared.
P1 has the line in state Invalid, from the second picture we see that there is no way to escape an Invalid state for a passive processor. Specifically, the *BusRd* input will set the state of line A to Invalid again (it is actually ignored).

So after the read from P2 we have:

```
P0: LineA -> Shared
P1: LineA -> Invalid
P2: LineA -> Shared
```